# Make a character move upwards on click

Tags: javascript

I am making a game similar to Flappy Bird. The character is supposed to move upwards when the browser window is clicked, but my code for this does not work. Here are the relevant lines of code:

```
var dudeYSpeed = 0;
var dudeXSpeed = 0;
var dudeJumping = false;
var jumpSpeed = -3;

if (mouseDown && dudeJumping === false){
    dudeJumping = true;
    dudeYSpeed = jumpSpeed;
} 
else {
    translateY += dudeYSpeed;
    dudeYSpeed += gravity;
    dudeJumping = false;
} 

translateX += dudeXSpeed;
```

Comment: `dudeXSpeed` will always be 0 so no translation will occur.

Comment: Is your title supposed to be “Make a character go up when I press a button in JavaScript”? Because you can’t “press” JavaScript and it doesn’t seem to be the “A” character going up.

Answer (score 0):

You only update `translateY` and `dudeYSpeed` if `dudeJumping` is true. You should update these variables in every frame, no matter what the input was.